# Input string was not in correct format when firing up MVC 3 app in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-express

I'm working on an MVC3 site at the moment, locally in IIS Express and VS2010.  The app worked fine until IIS Express hung and I had to terminate the process.

Since then, I get this YSoD when I run the site in VS2010 using IIS Express:

```
Input string was not in a correct format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.


Stack Trace: 

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument) +9566207
   System.Version.TryParseComponent(String component, String componentName, VersionResult& result, Int32& parsedComponent) +9549261
   System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result) +135
   System.Version.Parse(String input) +68
   System.Version..ctor(String version) +23
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetVersionFromVString(String version) +76
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderWithPropertyOptions(Type codeDomProviderType) +116
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderNonPublic(Type codeDomProviderType) +12
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder..ctor(CompilationSection compConfig, ICollection referencedAssemblies, CompilerType compilerType, String outputAssemblyName) +366
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +700
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +40
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +9118854
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +44
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +265

[HttpException (0x80004005): Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +62
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +421
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +691

[HttpException (0x80004005): Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

The stack trace doesn't seem to point to a code issue.  It's entirely possible that IIS Express is a red-herring and I've actually screwed up my code somewhere... but I'd expect the stack trace/debugger to catch that.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about tracking this down?

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit**

I've just tried it in the VS development server and got the same error, so presumably it's not IIS Express!

**Edit 2**

The project version (in AssemblyInfo.cs) looks like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("One_Page_Booking_Engine")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("One_Page_Booking_Engine")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("287108fb-4a0c-419f-8b35-a3bc0e2f8617")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

**Edit 3:**

I've now tried deleting the contents of `bin` and `obj`, restarted VS and rebooted my PC.  Nothing :( I've also tried publishing the site to a server with IIS and running it: I get exactly the same YSoD!

Comment: Have you closed your project and reopened it?  If so, try switching it back to the built in web server (casini) and then switch back.

Comment: What have you set the project version to? It should only consists of numbers.

Comment: Have you cleared your temporary ASP.NET files?  (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files)

Comment: I've tried re-opening VS and even a full reboot!  No success :( Cassini has exactly the same problem, so I guess it must be a code/configuration issue?

Comment: I've just tried clearing the ASP.Net temp folder (thanks, @dtryon) but it's still the same YSoD :(

Comment: @KarlLynch too bad, thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: Try deleting your bin and obj folders and then recompiling.

Comment: Good idea, @JohnKoerner, I've just tried that but still nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!

The issue was in my web.config.  I'd pulled down the template from HTML5BoilerPlate and ended up with this block:

```
<compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
```

Which is fine, except when I deployed it I changed the `value` from `v2.0` to `v4.0`.  Despite working initially, presumably running off a cache or something, that is what was causing it to cough up a hairball.

I've removed that whole `compilers` block and now it works fine!

Thank you for all the comments, everyone :)